Magento 2 UI Listing: show/hide grid columns based on condition
I am writing listing UI Component (local_comments_grid_listing.xml).
It has <dataSource> with <dataProvider class="Local\Comments\Ui\Component\DataProvider\ListingDataProvider">.
It works fine, but I need to hide column 'visibility' depends on current store mode (hide in single-store mode and show in multi-store mode).
I tried to implement ListingDataProvider::getMeta() method:
public function getMeta(): array
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();
    if ($this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        if(isset($meta['local_comments_grid_listing']['children']['visible'])) {
            unset($meta['local_comments_grid_listing']['children']['visible']);
        }
     }

    return $meta;
}

but it doesn't work (parent::getMeta() returns empty array)
What is the right way to do this ?

I solved my problem: I changed extends on my class (was on AbstractDataProvider)
class ListingDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
and refactor getData() and getMeta() methods.
now my column depends on current store setting
